# Using .Net 2.0 with Gallio

Tags: .net, runtime, gallio

I'm running tests with TD.Net and Gallio. I've got .Net 4.0 installed, but I want to use the 2.0 runtime. I've put `<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>` in my test assembly's app.config, but it still uses the 4.0.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the target framework to .Net 2.0 in your test assembly's properties?

Comment: Tried that, no luck. I had to switch to VS2008.